# lollipop update for hp 7 voice tab 1351ra

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

i am using hp 7 voice tab  1351ra

i am not getting update of lollipop operating system 
if you are interested to give the update from other external sources please give me or else please tell me might hp give update for this tablet?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [site](http://www.50lollipop.com/mp3-0/hp-7-voicetab-6784.html), the only way to get **lollipop** with your **HP tab**, is to use a **custom ROM**.

You will find **tutos** on this [site](http://www.50lollipop.com/mp3-0/hp-7-voicetab-6784.html) to upgrade your device.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Lollipop `Not available` yet for your Tablet.

[update for hp 7 voice tab](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Android-Tablets-e-g-HP-Slate-7/update-for-hp-7-voice-tab/td-p/4947727)

as Maxime said, you should use Custom Rom.Follow Below Link for find :

[Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

good day.